# NetworkError: 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: javascript, html, codeigniter

Tenho um código que forma a tela de perfil do usuário. Do lado do nome do mesmo ele tem a opção editar, que ao clicar abre um edit inline (**form-x-editable.html**). Até nessa parte está funcionando normalmente, mas ao clicar para salvar ele dá o erro ***NetworkError: 500 Internal Server Error***. Não sei o que pode está errado. Meu código está em MVC

View:

```
<span rel="tooltip" data-placement="right" data-original-title="Nome">
                            <a href="form-x-editable.html#" style="font-size: 14px;" id="nome" data-type="text" data-placement="top" data-pk="14" data-original-title="Nome">Editar</a>
                        </span>
```

Javascript:

```
var nome;
nome = '<?= $dados->nome ?>';
$('#nome').editable({
            url: '/Controller/editar',
            type: 'text',
            pk: 14,
            name: 'nome',
            title: 'Nome',
            params: function (comp) {
                comp.id_span = 'span14';
                comp.id = di_id;
                comp.e_id = epr_id;
                return comp;
            },
            ajaxOptions: {
                type: 'GET',
                dataType: 'json',
                contentType: 'application/json'
            },
            success: function (j) {
                $('#span14').html(j.nome);
                $('#dispName').empty();
                $('#dispName').html(j.nome);
            },
            value: nome,
            display: false
        });
```

Controller:

```
public function editar(){
        switch($this->input->get('id_span')){
            case 'span14':
                $data['nome'] = $this->input->get('value');
                $id = $this->input->get('id');
                $e_id = $this->input->get('e_id');
                $this->session->set_userdata('nome',$this->input->get('value'));
                $this->MT->editPerfil($id,$e_id,$data);
                break;
        }
        echo json_encode($data);
    }
}
```

Model:

```
public function editPerfil($id, $e_id, $data) {
        if ($this->vrfUsrEmp($e_id)) {
            if (isset($data['nome'])) {
                $this->db->set('nome', $data['nome']);
            }
            $this->db->where('id', $id);
            $this->db->where('e_id', $e_id);
            $this->db->update('NomeTabela');
            return $this->db->affected_rows();
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: No arquivo com problema, adicione no início: `ini_set('display_error', true); error_reporting(E_ALL);`

Comment: @rray fica como se não existisse esse código

Comment: Como assim? não entendi

Comment: Não teria como visualizar os erros no navegador

Comment: @GiancarloGiulian eu abri o Firebug para apresentar os erros do código e mostra isso quando eu clico para salvar a alteração

Comment: Boa noite, cara tu tá trabalhando como uma API REST?

Comment: Não tem algum lugar no seu CodeIgniter que permite mostrar erros ?